# How to search & replace in Python?

Tags: python

How can I add a character "-" to a string such as 'ABC-D1234', so it becomes 'ABC-D-1234'? 
Also, how can I add a character after the first 2 number, ie from 'ABC-D1234' to 'ABC-D12-34' Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the rule you are using to decide where to insert the extra character.

If you want it between the 5th and 6th characters you could try this:

```
s = s[:5] + '-' + s[5:]
```

If you want it after the first hyphen and then one more character:

```
i = s.index('-') + 2
s = s[:i] + '-' + s[i:]
```

If you want it just before the first digit:

```
import re
i = re.search('\d', s).start()
s = s[:i] + '-' + s[i:]
```

---

> Can I add a character after the first 2 number, ie from 'ABC-D1234' to 'ABC-D12-34'

Sure:

```
i = re.search('(?<=\d\d)', s).start()
s = s[:i] + '-' + s[i:]
```

or:

```
s = re.sub('(?<=\d\d)', '-', s, 1)
```

or:

```
s = re.sub('(\d\d)', r'\1-', s, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use slicing:

```
s = 'ABC-D1234'
s = s[0:5] + '-' + s[5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for this string?

```
>>> 'ABC-D1234'.replace('D1', 'D-1')
'ABC-D-1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking for the letter `D` and the next character `1` (the other answers take care of the general case), you could replace it with `D-1`:

```
s = 'ABC-D1234'.replace('D1', 'D-1')
```